# How to use an ArrayList inside a method that calls itself

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, class-variables

I have this code that is implemented in a class called `FileUtils`, which does what it sounds like.
All it does is it goes through a file and puts every folder under that folder in an `ArrayList`, so its like calling the `.listFiles()` method on any file that will return something.

```
private static ArrayList<File> classFileList = new ArrayList<File>();

public static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File dir) {
    if (!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()) 
        return null;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        classFileList.add(file);
        listFiles(file);
    }
    return classFileList;
}
```

The code above works fine but it requires a class variable `ArrayList` to work.

If I create the `ArrayList` inside the method then it gets reset every time it is recalled and only returns the last file. But with the set up I have now, if I call the method more than once then the list contains duplicates of every file.

Either a way to use a method variable or reset the class variable after it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter list for your method and call it from other method and initialize new list in that method and pass it to existing method. Expose new method instead of existing one :-

```
  public static ArrayList<File> listFilesWrapper(File dir){
     listFiles (dir , new ArrayList<File>());

   }

 public static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File dir,ArrayList<File> classFileList) {


if (!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()) 
    return null;
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    classFileList.add(file);
    listFiles(file , classFileList);
}
return classFileList;
}
```

Comment: Yea this what I thought of immediately after posting, I just did it and it works great so I think this is a good answer, however you need to pass classFileList and as a parameter when it is called in the for loop. as long as you make that edit I will accept this as the answer

Comment: @Totalllyrandomguy Done, thanks for pointing it out. Actually i didn't have java at this computer so wrote code in notepad. And copy pasted that part from your question. :-)

Comment: You need to pass file as well - listFiles() has 2 parameters! Also if you're passing classFileList as a parameter, the method should probably have void return type.

Comment: no it should not have void return type because this method is happening in a separate class form where it is needed. So it needs to make an arrayList internally, then needs return it to where ever it was called.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a local variable inside the function and `addAll` to it when calling recursively:

```
public static List<File> listFiles(File dir) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()) 
        return result; // Alternatively: return Collections.emptyList();

    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        result.add(file);
        result.addAll(listFiles(file));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Won't doing it this way be very processor intensive because you need to do run the method to find all the files and then call it again for everyFile?

Comment: ... same way as the OP has to - this isn't any more processor intensive.

Comment: @Panther that simply isn't true. Take a closer look - the last line of the for loop accumulates the results

Comment: @Panther I, of course, **did** test this. Did **you**? Local variables are redefined with each call - they do not "reset", they are simply different variables. Please try to actually run this before issuing such statements.

Comment: Could  you edit question , like add some space. I like remove my downvote and actually put up vote also. It is locked for me

Comment: @Panther Done. I replaced `add` with `addAll` in the first sentence - it also makes the it clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void listFiles(File dir, List<File> files) {
    if (!dir.isDirectory()) 
        return;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        files.add(file);
        listFiles(file, files);
    }
}
```

Then to get the list of all files in a directory, use this code;

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
listFiles(dir, files); // Now the result is contained in files.
```